# How to find the current nav Li "active" in bootstrap nav

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I need to get the current nav clicked in my bootstrap menu,
I know it has an "active" class added to the LI tag,
but after looking a lot online and on the bootstrap site,
Bootstrap does not seem to offer any JavaScript value containing the current nav...

anybody has an idea how to get this through a JavaScript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can get it like:

```
var $activeItem = $('.nav .active');
```

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT! Leaving this here in case anybody else needs the info :

var currentView = $(".nav li.active > a").text();

(Note that you need to have scroll spy enabled)